# JQuery drag/drop - applying css class based on different icons dropped in dropzone

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on a game system that has a series of ten icons. When each icon is dragged and dropped into a dropzone, I need to apply a new class to a specific div so it will show detailed info about that specific game.

So if I drag poker, I get the poker info, spades and I get spades info, etc..

Here is what I have so far

```
function initDragDrop() {
    $('.draggable').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    helper: 'clone',
    containment: 'parent',
    revert: true
  } );
  $('.dropspot').droppable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would probably want to use droppable for this. Specifically, check out the drop method: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop